# CSS Position - top 100% Is Not Equal To bottom 0

Tags: html, css, css-position

I noticed this when I assign `fixed` position to an element for css3 animation, that `top: 100%` isn't gave the same effect as `bottom: 0;`. It's locate the element outside of document, while `bottom:0;` is still showing the whole of the element.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bk96wv97/)**

Is there an opposite of css position `top:0;` that is automatically give the same effect as `bottom:0;`?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: It's understood, Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `top` value takes the top edge as a reference point, you need to use `transform: translateY(-100%)` to make the bottom edge a reference point.

```css
.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
}
.bottom {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top" style="padding:20px;border:1px solid #000;">TOP: 100%;</div>

<div class="bottom" style="padding:20px;border:1px solid #000;">BOTTOM: 0;</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If boxes are rendered in different heights, because e.g. the browser width changes, `translateY(-100%)` is working precisely, but `top: -100%` is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

```
.top{
    position:fixed;
    top: calc(100% - 60px);    
}
```

is equal to

```
.bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;    
}
```

```css
.top{
    position:fixed;
    top: calc(100% - 60px); /*60px the height of the element*/
    right: 0
}

.bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;  
    left: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="top" style="padding:20px;border:1px solid #000;">TOP: 100%;</div>

<div class="bottom" style="padding:20px;border:1px solid #000;">BOTTOM: 0;</div>
```

or

```css
.top{
    position:fixed;
    top: 100%; 
    margin-top: -60px; /*60px the height of the element*/
    right: 0
}

.bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;    
}
```

```html
<div class="top" style="padding:20px;border:1px solid #000;">TOP: 100%;</div>

<div class="bottom" style="padding:20px;border:1px solid #000;">BOTTOM: 0;</div>
```

Comment: how to calculate 60px, if padding 20px times 2 is 40px because there is top and bottom and border 1px times 2 is 2px equals 42px?